# file_get_contents() or cURL to handle 40* and 50* errors and 200 reponse code

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

I started my PHP script using `file_get_contents()`, I'm using an online data base and I can get JSON from it using URL, but sometimes (and I can't help it) I get back some 40* or 50* errors responses code, and I wondered if you guys could tell me what's better to use between cURL and `file_get_contents`, because basically everytime I'll have to check response code and switch case on it to determine what I do next.

- 200 => get file
- 403 => print "error"
- 502 => print 'bad gateway'
- ...

Hope I was clear, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### How to get the status of an HTTP response?

#### Using [cURL](https://www.php.net/book.curl)

The function [`curl_getinfo()`](https://php.net/curl_getinfo) get information regarding a specific transfer. The second parameter of this function allows to get a specific information. The constant `CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE` can be used to get the HTTP status code of the HTTP response.
`curl_getinfo()` should be called after `curl_exec()` and is relevant if `curl_exec()`' return is not false. If the response is `false`, don't forget to use [`curl_error()`](https://php.net/curl_error) in this case to get a readable string of the error.

```
$url = 'https://stackoverflow.com';
$curlHandle = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // required to get the HTTP header
$response = curl_exec($curlHandle);
$httpCode = $response !== false ? curl_getinfo($curlHandle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) : 0;
curl_close($curlHandle);
var_dump($httpCode); // int(200)
```

#### Using [streams](https://www.php.net/book.stream)

The function [`stream_get_meta_data()`](https://php.net/stream_get_meta_data) retrieves header/meta data from streams/file pointers

```php
$url = 'https://stackoverflow.com';
$httpCode = 0;
if ($fp = fopen($url, 'r')) {
    $data = stream_get_meta_data($fp);
    [$proto, $httpCode, $msg] = explode(' ', $data['wrapper_data'][0] ?? '- 0 -');
}
fclose($fp);
var_dump($httpCode); // int(200)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do I have to setopt everytime I exec the request?

Comment: @AxelCarré That said, [`curl_init()`](https://php.net/curl_init) initializes a cURL session. So, it seems that until you do not close this session, the option are defined (or until the PHP script ends, of course).